# Return list of columns in user-provided subquery

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to fill a ComboBox of all columns from results of a query. That query is submitted by the user on the form, so the program needs to run the query then have a procedure run that extracts just the column names. I know the following works for a typical table:

```
SELECT
    c.name 'Column Name'
FROM
    sys.columns c
WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('Vendor')
```

What would be the best way to insert the user query (select * from vendor) as a subselect and get the same result?

Edit:
I could do(as Thomas Stringer noted):

```
for (int i=0; i < dataSet.Tables["Vendor"].Columns.Count; i++ )
{
    ColumnChoices.Items.Add(dataSet.Tables["Vendor"].Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString());
}
```

...though that isn't very efficient because it requires loading all of the data into the dataset when I really only want the columns.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  If so, what version?

Comment: This would be using a Visual Studio DataSet and DataAdapter. According to the Microsoft website, it supports commands of SQL Server database (version 7.0 or later.)

Comment: Would `SELECT TOP (0) * FROM (user_query);` work?

Comment: @ypercube "SELECT TOP (0) * FROM (select * from vendor) as userQuery", thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just pull the `DataTable` object(s) and enumerate the `DataColumnCollection`.  Here is some sample code to show how you can enumerate the collection and dump the column names:

```
DataTable queryResults = // get your data

foreach (DataColumn column in queryResults.Columns)
    Console.WriteLine("Column Name :: {0}", column.ColumnName);
```

Of course this is an extremely rudimentary illustration, but it shows what you need:

[image]

Comment: Prefix the query with "SET FMTONLY ON;", then you won't actually execute the query

    string FmtQuery = "set fmtonly on; " + Query;

Comment: Of course, you should also employ some injection protection.

Comment: @MisterMagoo This was just to illustrate how to do this.  There are 100s of omitted things that should be in development, but to keep code brief I kept them out.

Comment: @MisterMagoo There you go :-) Only the necessary code to eliminate any confusion.

Comment: Sorry Thomas, I realise now that seemed critical of your code, but wasn't meant to be. I didn't want to post a new answer, just add that using SET FMTONLY ON would be a less invasive way to retrieve metadata. I added the second comment about injection because my included code was missing it, not as a comment on yours. Apologies.

Comment: @MisterMagoo No problem at all!